# How to insert a row in DataFrame in pandas? (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row

Say I have the following dataframe:

```
a=np.array([[10,20,30,40],[5,20,35,50],[0,5,10,15]])
b=pd.DataFrame(a, columns=["n1", "n2", "n3", "n4"])
```

I do the following calculation on it (difference between 1st and 2nd row):

```
c=b.diff(1,0)
c.loc[[1]]
```

And then I want to insert this row of differences (given by `c.loc[[1]]`) into my dataframe `b`. How do I do that? When I try, I get an error `ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [setting with enlargement](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement) by `Series` selected by `loc` with one `[]`:

```
b.loc[len(b)] = b.diff().loc[1]
print (b)
     n1    n2    n3    n4
0  10.0  20.0  30.0  40.0
1   5.0  20.0  35.0  50.0
2   0.0   5.0  10.0  15.0
3  -5.0   0.0   5.0  10.0
```

Or use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with `DataFrame` with `[[]]`:

```
c = pd.concat([b, b.diff().loc[[1]]], ignore_index=True)
print (c)

     n1    n2    n3    n4
0  10.0  20.0  30.0  40.0
1   5.0  20.0  35.0  50.0
2   0.0   5.0  10.0  15.0
3  -5.0   0.0   5.0  10.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
c = b.diff(axis=0).iloc[1]
```

or

```
c = b.diff(axis=0).loc[1]
```

The output:

```
print(c)
    n1    -5.0
    n2     0.0
    n3     5.0
    n4    10.0
    Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

to add c to b use append

```
b = b.append(c)
```

output of `print(b)`

```
     n1    n2    n3    n4
0  10.0  20.0  30.0  40.0
1   5.0  20.0  35.0  50.0
2   0.0   5.0  10.0  15.0
1  -5.0   0.0   5.0  10.0
```